# Alter the Grid option in Tumblr with CSS?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am using Tumblr for a blog that I have created and have it set on the Grid mode, where the posts come out as a grid of multiple columns.

When expanding the browser window, the columns multiply in the Grid Layout.

All I would like to do is, when the browser window is spread out, I would like the columns to stay 4 columns instead of expanding to 5 columns.

Is this possible?

```
.index-page.grid #posts.masonry {
box-sizing: content-box;
}
.index-page.grid #posts, .index-page.grid.no-results #posts.masonry {
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#posts, #posts.no-title-desc.avatar-style-hidden {
margin-top: 50px;
}
.content {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 1px 20px;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
max-width: 702px;
min-width: 270px;
}
.clearfix {
zoom: 1;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section,
summary{
display: block;
}
user agent stylesheetarticle, aside, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section {
display: block;
}
Pseudo ::before element
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
display: table;
content: "";
}
Pseudo ::after element
.clearfix:after {
clear: both;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
display: table;
content: "";
}
```

Comment: Ohh sorry about that. I have used the developer tools on the Chrome Browser and have tried changing many things on the CSS end, but doesn't seem to do anything. I have tried playing with index-page.grid #posts part of it and tried to change the max width, but just moves the container to the right.